# Using SQLAlchemy-DataTables with Multiple Relationships Between the Same Tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy-DataTables to do server-side processing of the data for the jQuery DataTables plugin, but have run into an issue trying to create the DataTables columns model.

My data models look something like:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(64))
    #...
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    creator = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[creator_id])
    created_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_modifier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    last_modifier = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[last_modifier_id])
    modified_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    #...
```

My views.py file (yes, this is a Flask application) then looks something like:

```
@posts.route('/data')
def data():

# Column definition for SQLAlchemy-DataTables
columns = [
    ColumnDT(Post.id),
    ColumnDT(Post.subject),
    ColumnDT(User.username), # for creator
    ColumnDT(User.username), # for last modifier... this is the problem
    ColumnDT(Post.modified_time)
]

# Query definition
query = db.session.query().\
    select_from(Post).\
    outerjoin(User, Post.creator_id==User.id).\
    outerjoin(User, Post.last_modifier_id==User.id) # second error here

# Request parameters
params = request.args.to_dict()

# Instantiating a DataTable for the query and table needed
rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)

# Returns DataTable JSON
return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

There are two issues with the code that I could use guidance on:

1. What is the best way to do the multiple joins between the same tables in the query definition?
2. How do I set up the column definitions to reference the same data model attribute (User.username) for multiple relationships (creator, last_modifier)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to join the same table multiple times you need [aliases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases):

```
In [9]: creator = db.aliased(User)

In [10]: last_modifier = db.aliased(User)
```

Then define your columns using said aliases:

```
In [11]: columns = [
    ...:     ColumnDT(Post.id),
    ...:     ColumnDT(Post.subject),
    ...:     ColumnDT(creator.username),
    ...:     ColumnDT(last_modifier.username),
    ...:     ColumnDT(Post.modified_time)
    ...: ]
    ...:
```

Finally, form the query:

```
In [12]: query = db.session.query().\
    ...:     select_from(Post).\
    ...:     outerjoin(creator, Post.creator).\
    ...:     outerjoin(last_modifier, Post.last_modifier)
```